# Is introducing a try-catch block in JavaScript considered bad with respect to performance?

Tags: javascript, try-catch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript Try-Catch Performance Vs. Error Checking Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217294/javascript-try-catch-performance-vs-error-checking-code)

A colleague of mine told me that using a lot of try catch blocks in javascript is going to be a hit in performance . Is that claim true and if yes then why  ?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217294/javascript-try-catch-performance-vs-error-checking-code

Comment: @Geek I like your rating, Don't change it a bit!

Comment: @BillyMoon I'm forced to down vote ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer, yes he is correct. A `try/catch` statement has do to certain things under the hood in order to work. For instance, it will extend the *scope lookup chain* (which might not be that big problem in modern environments) but it especially needs to *evaluate* whatever code is within that `try-block`, to figure if there are any errors thrown.

Anyway, `try/catch` blocks are a great opportunity to make your code stable. However, you should always apply it on the smallest fraction of your code possible and of course only, if it is *really* needed (like, avoiding browser specific bugs/errors which you can't work around). Just putting like all of your script into one big `try/catch` block, is certainly the worst idea.

Comment: What do you mean by "*especially needs to evaluate the code within the `try`-block*" - wouldn't one need to do that anyway, without try-catch?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There is a [good article on that](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/efficient-javascript/?page=2#trycatch) at dev.opera.com.

This is likely because try-catch-blocks have that certain, unusual handling of result objects, they need to check whether its type is `throw`. And then, executing the `catch` block is not as easy as it looks in the code. See [Ecmascript §12.14: The `try` Statement](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.14) for further reading.

Still, try-catch-clauses are a powerful feature, and one should use them where appropriate and useful. But instead of having them inside performance-critical functions, you should wrap them around so they are not executed too often.