# Way to differentiate between declared variable vs undeclared

Tags: javascript

I have a problem.
I will only declare a variable if that satisfies my condition.

```
if(//some condition1)
var some1=1;
else if(//some condition1)
var some2=2;
```

Now

```
var some3=some1+some2;
```

if two conditions are met, it is okay to have sum in `some3;`

if only one condition is met, I want to have either `some1` or `some2` in `some3`

How can I achieve this?

Note: Thanks for answers But i want to declare variables only if that condition is met.
Is there any other solution?

Comment: why not just declare the variable first and then just set their values when it meets the conditions

Comment: @Loney you check for the if(var == undefined) condition then do the addition of only defined one

Comment: @captain Do you mean `if(typeof var === "undefined")` ?

Comment: @Grallen I mean to say `var == undefined` .Why to check `typeof`.Lets say var1 is undefined then you check `if (var1 == undefined)` add only `var2` and `var3`

Comment: What's the harm in declaring variables when the condition isn't met?

Comment: Remember that because of the way Javascript hoists variable declarations, a declaration in an `if` statement is hoisted into the function, even if the condition isn't met.

Comment: very bad coding practice...

Comment: View my posted answer.. :)

Comment: @captain: I honestly can't remember which issue I converted to this syntax to avoid.

Comment: simpler is better. it's easier to understand and less code.

Comment: The question title doesn't seem to match with your question. To find out whether a variable is declared you have to try to access it: `try { foo; } catch() { /* foo is not declared */ }`. But you seem to be asking something else in your actual question, so please update the title.

Comment: @Lonely why do want to declare variables only if a condition is met? what advantage do you expect?

Comment: @all : please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17991100/way-to-differentiate-between-declared-variable-vs-undeclared-2

Comment: @Lonely did you check the answers ?

Comment: @Deepanshu Ya checked, but it is not the question I wanted.
I can't able to clearly state my problem
so asked another question.
Thanks for help

Answer (score 3):

```
var some3=0;

if(//some condition1){
  var some1=1;
  some3 += some1;
}else if(some condition2){
  var some2=2;
  some3 += some2;
}
```

> EDIT: A better option :

```
var some3=0;           
if(some condition1){
   some3 += 1;
}else if(some condition2){
   some3 += 2;
}
```

and moreover both conditions wont meet at same time, so, if you want to you can do like below also

```
var some3=0;           
if(some condition1){
   some3 += 1;
}
if(some condition2){
   some3 += 2;
}
```

Comment: @Deepenshu question says variable should be declared only if condition is true

Comment: Good logic, but you are re-declaring your variables. Could also improve the formatting a bit

Comment: @Deepanshu Please check question.It says **declare variables only if that condition is met**

Comment: no need to declare some1 and some2 here. you can just directly add it to some3.

Comment: I think the OP means `defined` and `undefined` rather than `declared` and `undeclared`. With `var some3;` I declare the variable but it is still undefined. Declaring the variable (even inside the if) will declare it locally for the full function scope.

Comment: @artsylar you don't know if OP needs the separate values later on

Comment: well now I have no idea what is the requirement... what i thought should be the best , I typed it down !!! because checking the variable for undefined and stuff is just so many lines of code for nothng

Comment: Your code is fine ... the point is that the OP didn't know that a) undefined is not the same as undeclared and b) that declaring and defining a variable later in the scope will result in it being declared earlier and defined later as described by basilikum

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you can't declare your variables only if a certain condition is satisfied. JavaScript has function scope which means, that no matter where in your code you write `var some1`, it will always be hoisted up, to the top of the function scope:

```
function A() {
   if (...) {
       var a = 1;
   }
}
```

will be interpreted as:

```
function A() {
   var a;
   if (...) {
       a = 1;
   }
}
```

That being said. I think to solve your problem you just need to initialize your variables with 0:

```
var some1 = 0,
    some2 = 0,
    some3;

if(//some condition1)
    some1 = 1;
else if(//some condition1)
    some2 = 2;

some3 = some1 + some2;
```

**EDIT**

Actually, there IS a way to to declare variables only when a condition is satisfied:

```
if (...) {
    eval("var x = 1;");
}
```

But I don't really see any need for a "hack" like that and wouldn't advice that method at all.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize both variables to 0 first.

```
var some1 = 0, some2 = 0;
if (condition1) {
    some1 = 1;
}
if (condition2) {
    some2 = 2;
}
var some3 = some1 + some2;
```

Since you want to allow both conditions to be met and set both variables, you should not use `else if`. Just two separate `if` statements.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(//some condition1) {
    var some1 = 1;
} else if(//some condition1) {
    var some2 = 2;
}

var some3 = 0;

if(some1 !== undefined) {
    some3 += some1;
}
if(some2 !== undefined) {
    some3 += some2;
}
```

Comment: This seems the right answer to me. Only one suggestion, use the comparison to `null` or using `typeof some1 === 'undefined'`, since comparing to `undefined` is not totally safe

Comment: Why isn't it totally safe ?

Comment: Because in older environments it was possible to override the value of `undefined` and change it, for example, to `true`, which would break a lot of things.

Comment: Well that would help people getting rid of their obsolete stuff.

Answer (score 1):

How about an object:

```
var obj = {};
if(//conditon){
   obj.some1 = 1;
}
else if(//condition){
   obj.some2 = 1;
}

var sum3 = 0;
for(var key in obj){
    sum3 += obj[key];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why not just declare the variable first and then just set their values when it meets the conditions

```
var some1 = 0;
var some2 = 0;

if (//some condition)
{
  some1 = 1;
}
if (// some condition)
{
  some2 = 2;
}

var some3 = some1 + some2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare all the variables in the begin. Initialize them to 0. If the condition is met, change the variable value. Then, when you make the sum, any value plus 0 remains the same. Or if the condition was met, the value won't be 0.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use that model, you could just use a fourth variable.

```
var some0 = 0
if(/*some condition1*/) {
var some1=1;
some0 = some1 + some3
}
else if(/*some condition1*/) {
var some2=2;
some0 = some2 + some3
}
some3=some0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var some3 = 0; //Assingning global var.
if(//some condition1)
  var some1=1;
else if(//some condition1)
  var some2=2;
```

In Conditions

```
if(some1 != null && some2 != null )
  some3=some1+some2;
else if(some1 != null && some2 == null)
  some3=some1;
else if(some1 == null && some2 != null)
  some3=some2;
else if(some1 == null && some2 == null)
  some3=some3;
```

Then

```
alert(some3);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
var some3 =
(2 > 4      ? 10:0) +
(5 < 8      ? 20:0) +
(10 == 11   ? 30:0) +
('a' < 'b'  ? 40:0) ;
```

I admit this does not look pretty.

Answer (score 0):

you an use the

> if(//some condition1) var some1=1;
>
> else if(//some condition1) var some2=2;

and then try catch statements like in my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FZqZN/12312/)

```
try{

 var some3=some1+some2;

}
catch (e){
    try{
      var some3=some1;
      document.getElementById("test").innerHTML= some3;

    }catch (e){
        try{
           var some3=some2 ;
           document.getElementById("test").innerHTML= some3;

        }
        catch (e){
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML="Something went wrong!!!!or no condition satisfied";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: (The use of exceptions is inefficient, because of the overhead of throwing exceptions, but I was just giving an extra option form the other answers.)
more info about the side effects of try catch in an [old question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217294/javascript-try-catch-performance-vs-error-checking-code).
In order to answer that question @jon-j created this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mct5N/) which proves this.