# Does javascript have anything like a try catch?

Tags: javascript

I have the following class:

```
var a = $scope.option.userMap[userId].name;
```

This fails when there is no value in userMap that has a key of userId. The error message comes up when it tries to do the .name of something that's not defined.

Is there a simple way that I could catch this error? When the error happens I would like the variable `a` to be set to "unknown"

Comment: Yes, JavaScript has `try`/`catch`.

Comment: Did you tried Google First? - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it could have been solved by taking a look at the language's documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript has something exactly like try / catch, but why use it when you can just check if the key exists instead :

```
if (userId in $scope.option.userMap) {

    var a = $scope.option.userMap[userId].name;

}else{

    var a = 'unknown';

}
```

Comment: Very good, except `a` should be set to "unknown" :)

Comment: @Jongware - Yeah, that's probably better ;-)

Comment: +1, by the way, for answering the Question Not Asked: [Blindly using `try-catch` or checking your code for errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217294/javascript-try-catch-performance-vs-error-checking-code)

Answer (score 5):

Yes.

```
try {
    var a = $scope.option.userMap[userId].name;
} catch(e) {
    //catch a error
} finally {
    //execute always
}
```

About `finally` block vs `return` statement:

```
function something() {
    try {
        return $scope.option.userMap[userId].name;
    } catch(e) {
        return e.message
    } finally {
        alert('Yohoooo!')
    }
}
```

You will always see the `alert` when call the `something` function.

Answer (score 1):

Of course:

```
try {
   // Live hard...dangerous code
} catch(e) {
   // Manage your mess
}
```

Optionall you can add a finally clause, that is always executed:

```
finally {
    // Always executed
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is.

This is the syntax:

```
try {
    //Run some code here
} catch(err) {
    //Handle errors here
}
```

For more information:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_errors.asp

Comment: Download the plugin listed in my profile description

Answer (score 1):

Though the replies above have answered the question of whether JS has try/catch feature, they have failed to point out the fact that it is not best practice to use try/catch blocks to work around undefined variables. Better way to do this is:

```
var userObj = $scope.option.userMap[userId];
var a = userObj ? userObj.name : undefined;
```